# How to write each IP address in a different line of a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from scapy.all import *


pkts = rdpcap("lalalao.pcap")

for p in pkts:
##  print p.time


        if IP in p: #if packet has IP layer
                    src_ip = p[IP].src
                    dest_ip = p[IP].dst
                    print src_ip

                    f = open('IP_src.txt', 'a+')
                    for ip in src_ip:
                            f.writelines(ip)

                    f.close()
```

How to write each ip in a different line of the text file? The code is not working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`writelines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) does not add newline.

> Write a list of lines to the stream. **Line separators
>   are not added**, so it is usual for each of the lines provided to have a
>   line separator at the end.

---

Use [`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) ([`print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) in Python 3.x) which write newline at the end of the string:

```
with open('IP_src.txt', 'a+') as f:
    for ip in src_ip:
        print >>f, ip         # Python 2.x
        # print(ip, file=f)   # Python 3.x
```

Or append the line manually:

```
with open('IP_src.txt', 'a+') as f:
    for ip in src_ip:
        f.write(ip + '\n')
```